# Check equality of 2 variables in Github Action

Tags: yaml, github-actions

If a tag is started with `v` pushed to the branch, a release will be make. Here is the issue: people may forgot pump up the version before release. Therefore check equality between tagged version and the version in the code is needed

The version in the code can fetch by `poetry version -s` and then a letter `v` is needed to add to the front of the version string (please see below)

`VERSION_CODE = "v""$(poetry version -s)"`

The version from the git tag can be access as below

`VERSION_TAG = $(git describe --exact-match --tags $(git log -n1 --pretty='%h'))`

**Question:** How can I check the equality of `VERSION_CODE` and `VERSION_TAG` so that the pipeline will make a release if the value of them are alined?

The code I have for now is shown below. There is an error message for step `if: VERSION_CODE != VERSION_TAG` that there is **an unrecognised named-value: 'VERSION_CODE'. Located at position 1 within expression: VERSION_CODE**

```
name: Release By Tag

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - "v*" # Push events to matching v*, i.e. v1.0, v20.15.10

jobs:
  version-check:
    name: check version
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
       
       ... set up environment, ex install poetry 

       - name: try to fail version check
         run: |
           VERSION_CODE = "v""$(poetry version -s)"
           VERSION_TAG = $(git describe --exact-match --tags $(git log -n1 --pretty='%h')
         if: VERSION_CODE != VERSION_TAG
         run: exit 1

       - name: version is correct
         run: echo "version tag is alined"

       ... make a release
```

Comment: I think the easiest way to achieve what you want would be to use [outputs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter), and check in the following steps if the condition is true or false to perform the operation you want.

Comment: @GuiFalourd but how can I use `outputs` to assign values from evaluation an expression? `::set-output name={name}::{{expression}}`?

Comment: Grzegorz Krukowski shows you how in his answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass variables to next step - `if` checking happens before step is executed, so you cannot access it as you posted. Also `exit 1` is not the right pattern, you rather need to generate variables, pass them around and them use them in next steps.

One solution will be:

```
name: Release By Tag

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - "v*" # Push events to matching v*, i.e. v1.0, v20.15.10

jobs:
  version-check:
    name: check version
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
       
       ... set up environment, ex install poetry 

       - name: try to fail version check
         id: version_info
         run: |
           VERSION_CODE="v""$(poetry version -s)"
           VERSION_TAG=$(git describe --exact-match --tags $(git log -n1 --pretty='%h')
           echo "::set-output name=VERSION_CODE::$VERSION_CODE"
           echo "::set-output name=VERSION_TAG::$VERSION_TAG"

       - name: version is correct
         if: ${{ steps.version_info.outputs.VERSION_CODE == steps.version_info.outputs.VERSION_TAG }}
         run: echo "version tag is alined"

       ... make a release
```

You can also check if those values are matching in your first step and pass just boolean to the next step - depending on your needs.

Comment: seems the script is not able to run by this way, I got following error message `VERSION_CODE: command not found`
`Error: Process completed with exit code 127.`

Comment: Oh yeah, there were some unnecessary spaces in there, VERSION_CODE="" instead of VERSION_CODE = "" is the right way to go in Bash - I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot Grzegroz, but the version is correct step is always skipped, I somehow can not make it run, do you may be know the reason?

Comment: Can you print those values and show the workflow output ? maybe there are some whitespaces there